# Checkbox data in column?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database-design, checkbox

a training course database should get a update.
right now every new user (editable by client's client) is stored into a given training course (editable by the client). the users are counted, so that there are never more than f.a. 12 users for each training course.

**okay that was the old concept.**

for the new one, every new user could be subscribed to more courses than one with checkboxes.
the difficulty for me is now, that i'm having troubles to deal with the array concept in the SELECT/DELETE/UPDATE-statements in the given column (sID which is the training id)

**Table training courses:**

```
id | from_date             | til_date |          | ...   
---+-----------------------+---------------------+---------
2  |  2012-04-16 08:30:00  | 2012-04-16 08:30:00 | ...
```

**Table training users:**

```
id | sID | name     | ...                          
---+-----+----------+---------------------------------------
1  |  2  | User A   | ...
2  |  6  | User B   | ...
```

i liked the concept about writing the different courses in one column (2,4,7,9) seperated by ",".
but than i will have the problem that i can't do a COUNT on that column any more. also the safed course data is only outputting the checked courses to the checkboxes. but the client's client have to update the course members manually. so i can't "hardcode" every course to a checkbox.

does anybody have an idea how to do this properly?

thanks and greetings,
bernard

Answer (score 1):

You'd need at least three tables.

```
courses: (id, name, etc....)
users: (id, name, etc....)
user_courses: (user_id, course_id)
```

Adding/removing a user from a course would involve updates on the user_courses table only. New user: add a record, old user: delete a record. Each user/course pairing gets ONE record to themselves in user_courses, and you can still do your counts quite easily.

Embedding comma-separated values into a field negates the entire purpose of a relational data. You lose the ability to relate data to each other, because your nice clean user<->course mappings are in this big blob of numbers/commas that the DB cannot interpret for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a union table between `users` and `courses`. Using a comma separated field is pretty hacky for what you're doing here.

Users:

```
user_id | user_name | ...
```

Courses:

```
user_id | course_name | ...
```

User_Course_Union

```
union_id | user_id | course_id | ...
```

Then you can easily do queries based off of `SELECT COUNT(union_id) AS count WHERE ...` and get all the data you'll need.

Comment: thanks for your response. but doesn't this need a additional step in the input mask? (new user > then select the course to the user)

Answer (score 0):

When you have a [many-to-many](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) relationship (e.g. courses to students) you typically should utilize a table in-between them. That is, you should have your course table, your student table, and then your course-student table (or "enrollment" table). The enrollment table could look like this:

```
Id | Student | Course | Grade    |
1  | A       | 10     | Pass     |
2  | B       | 10     | Fail     |
3  | A       | 12     | Withdraw |
```

This shows student A in two courses (10 and 12), and two students (A and B) in course 10. A benefit of doing it this way is that you can keep data that is specific to the enrollment, such as grades or pass/fail status (as shown in the example).

Answer (score 0):

I would do three tables. `userInformation`, `courseInformation` and `userCourseInformation`. `userCourseInformation` would keep which user is taking which courses.

```
userInformation
user_id, user_name, etc..

courseInformation
course_id, course_name, etc..

userCourseInformation
user_course_id, user_id, course_id, etc..
```

All of the enrolled courses go on the `userCourseInformation` and reference the other two tables `id` as foreign keys. When you want to offer a new course, you add it to `courseInformation`. Add a new user, create a new `userInformation`. The majority of the UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT will happen on the `userCourseInformation` as students come and go. You could also just use a flag (boolean) to show is active or not. It means you can always go back and look at past data.